# Asp.net mvc4 common data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there best practise to share database data accross controllers and ViewModel.
For example: products and catgories which I would like to have available (one case should be to provide a List of the categories in the edit view of the products in the admin area of the site) and I would like to have this data updated in case of modification (ie in the previous case adding a category...).
I would not want to have the same piece of code reading the database (I'm using EF5) in each controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Repository pattern to achieve one or more of the following objectives:

- You want to maximize the amount of code that can be tested with
  automation and to isolate the data layer to support unit testing.
- **You access the data source from many locations and want to apply
  centrally managed, consistent access rules and logic.**
- You want to implement and centralize a caching strategy for the data
  source.
- You want to improve the code's maintainability and readability by
  separating business logic from data or service access logic.
- You want to use business entities that are strongly typed so that you
  can identify problems at compile time instead of at run time.
- You want to associate a behavior with the related data. For example,
  you want to calculate fields or enforce complex relationships or
  business rules between the data elements within an entity.
- You want to apply a domain model to simplify complex business logic.

More information here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Comment: Thanks to put me on the repository track. The link is too much sharepoint oriented. So I did a generic repository interface and implemented repositories class for each of the class where I wanted a common access

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do :)